# How to set tooltip show time in app builder?

Tags: tooltip, progress-4gl, openedge

Can you increase the time the tooltip is shown on components in .w files made from the app-builder?
Maybe it's a windows setting?

Running: OpenEdge Release: 11.3.2. Windows 7 & 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible with the ABL.
It can be done with the UltraTooltipsManager in the GUI for .NET.